# How to deploy to custom server from Travis with script

Tags: shell, ubuntu, ssh, continuous-integration, travis-ci

My current CI has github hook to run travis tests. I want to add `deploy` feature to my Travis config that runs a bash script that will ssh into my server and do a git pull. Is this possible? Eg:

- Travis runs tests and then runs deploy `provider: script` `bash scripts/deploy.sh`
- The script ssh into my server (pw can be Travis ENV var)
- Deploy script does a git pull

Note: my server is Ubuntu and I have full root access and dedicated IP.

Answer (score 0):

well, there are 2 methods come to me, to solve your problem.

you can use *expect* command, which is written with TCL, to interact with the ssh command, when it need to input password. you can check this [article](https://www.journaldev.com/1405/expect-script-ssh-example-tutorial)

The second method, is not using password, but a private key, to access the remote server, without having to input password. you can use ssh-keygen to generate a pair of keys, which will be stored as $home/.ssh/id_rsa and $home/.ssh/id_rsa.pub, the one with a suffix pub is the public key, you can put it in the remote server: $home/.ssh/authorized_keys, then you will not need password any more

Comment: but how to add that private key to either travis.yml or the bash script?

Answer (score 0):

If you have root access to your server then save below codes inside a file called "server-setup.sh" in your local machine.

```
chmod +x server-setup.sh
execute ./server-setup.sh
```

#### server-setup.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Creating a separate user who have deploy access on your server"
read -p 'Server Address ' SERVER
read -p 'Deploy User Name ' USER

# Generate ssh key pair
ssh-keygen -t rsa -N "" -f ${USER}_rsa
PUB_KEY=$(cat ${USER}_rsa.pub)
PRV_KEY=$(cat ${USER}_rsa)

# Encrypt private key with your CI tool
travis encrypt-file ${USER}_rsa ./travis/${USER}_rsa.enc --add --force

# Add rsa keys to gitignore
echo ${USER}_rsa >> .gitignore
echo ${USER}_rsa.pub >> .gitignore

ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@"${SERVER}" << EOF
sudo adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" ${USER}
echo "travis ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers.d/${USER}
chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/${USER}
sudo usermod -a -G docker ${USER}

sudo su ${USER}
cd ~
mkdir ~/.ssh
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
echo "${PUB_KEY}" >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Add ssh key to help cloning private github repo
echo "${PRV_KEY}" >> ~/.ssh/github_rsa
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/github_rsa
eval \$(ssh-agent)
ssh-add ~/.ssh/github_rsa
ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
echo IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_rsa >> ~/.ssh/config
EOF

echo *********************************************************************************************************
echo "Go to https://github.com/"$(git config --get travis.slug)"/settings/keys/new and add the below text :-"
echo ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo ${PUB_KEY}
echo ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

See one example here .travis.yml file and travis/deploy.sh file : [Example](https://github.com/dbjpanda/drupal-on-docker)

Note: But `git pull` is not a good idea. It is better to build your artifacts or any dependencies on travis itself and use scp or something else to copy those artifacts from travis to your server over ssh. Or first go to your server, pull the github repo, then configure that repo on server to accept push from travis.